# Newline disappears in Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, newline, paste

My problem is the following: I have to insert a multi-line text from a PDF to an Excel sheet. If I double-click on the cell and paste, it will paste it all, in multiple lines. I, however, need it in a single line. So if I disable "wrap text", the text is in a single line, but the line breaks disappear. Ex:

this

should

be

separate

This becomes thisshouldbeseparate when I un-wrap the cell. 
I tried find&replace with "¶" and alt-010, but it can't find any such characters. 
Any ideas?

Edit: as far as I can tell, the issue is with the version of windows. It works on Windows 8.1, but not on 7. I need to get it working on 7.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the issue related to the copying because what you see is just 3 text objects drawn in different positions. As they are not a single text objects with spaces and linebreaks inside so *visual* linebreaks are not re-created.

Try this free tool: [PDF Multitool](https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html) utility that is capable of recreating the formatting similar to the visual one (make sure you have `preserve formatting` enabled when extracting or copying text).

If you are interested in automating then text extraction API is also available (not free).

Disclosure: I'm related to [ByteScout](https://bytescout.com), maker of free PDF Multitool utility